# What is the name of the song that plays in Noragami Aragoto Episode 10 during the Okinunishi scene?

Tags: music, noragami

Does anyone know the name of the song from Episode 10 of Noragami Aragoto which plays at 14:55 when Okuninushi told that lady to move? I really want to know what the name of that song is.

Answer (score 4):

The song is from Disc 1 Track 15.

Its name is 大国譚 ("Daikokutan"), although I don't know if there's any official English translation of the same.

You can listen to it [here](http://www.kuwo.cn/yinyue/6737161/).

Comment: thanks, i really wanted to know the name of the song so bad.

Comment: @Azurakai No problem. If this answers your question, you can select the tick mark/check mark beside the answer to indicate that this question has been answered.